# When do writes on a socket block?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, blocking

I'm writing a network application based on an epoll loop and thread pool for handling requests. In each thread I take special care not to block on client reads, by using non-blocking sockets and returning as soon as read returns EAGAIN (or EWOULDBLOCK to be POSIX compliant...).

Should I take special care in socket writes too? I don't see myself sending enough data to fill the system TCP buffers, and blocking for a while shouldn't be too harmful. Is this the **only case** where a write on a socket blocks? Not enough buffer size?

Also, can a socket be declared non-blocking for reads and blocking for writes? Or should I use fcntl all the time to switch between these behaviours?

Thanks!

Comment: You can leave the socket blocking and use `recvfrom` with `MSG_DONTWAIT` to do non-blocking receives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only case where a write on a socket blocks is when the data written won't fit in the buffer. Ideally, you would handle writes much the way you handle reads. You don't need to switch before each write. If you want to block on write, use this logic:

1. Perform the write.
2. If it completes, you're done.
3. Switch the socket to blocking.
4. Perform the (rest of) the write.
5. Switch the socket back to non-blocking.

Comment: "The only case where a write on a socket blocks is when the data written won't fit in the buffer". Fair enough! One question though: Why try a non-blocking write first and not just do steps 3-5? Is fcntl expensive?

Comment: @Guido You turn one operation into three operations. It's not that `fcntl` is specifically expensive, it's that it necessarily requires a user-to-kernel transition.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to handle this is to use non-blocking I/O throughout given that you're using non-blocking reads. When you do a write, if you get -1/EWOULDBLOCK, start selecting on that socket for writeability, and when you get it, retry the write. If that succeeds, stop selecting on writeability for that socket. Don't switch to blocking-mode for that socket, it defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: I know, but I was thinking blocking writes should be very very few and not fatal to my application. Therefore the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Guido When you have a write that blocks, you are stuck. The idea of using select() is that you only ever get stuck in select(). If you use blocking writes you will hold up your entire application. You don't *ever* want to do this. If a socket becomes write-blocked for too long it means the peer isn't reading: you might want to consider dropping the connection altogether as it is clearly misbehaving. You can't accomplish any of that by using blocking write.